# I have a (likely incorrect) proof that seems to make Maschke's theorem pointless, but I can't figure out what is wrong with it.

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations, representation-theory

This is the statement I have seemed to prove:
For a group representation $\rho:G\mapsto GL(V)$, and $W,W^c\leq V$ such that $W\oplus W^c = V$ and $W\cap W^c= ${$0$}, if $W$ is invariant under the representation, then so is $W^c$.

The proof:
Suppose $v\in W^c$ such that $\rho(g)v=w\in W$, for $g\in G$. Then, $W^c\ni v = \rho(e)v = \rho(g^{-1}g)v = \rho(g^{-1})w\in W$, since $W$ is invariant under the representation. Then, $v = 0$, and $W^c$ is a sub-representation.

This seems to imply that every sub-representation whose complement is a corresponding sub-representation such that their direct sum is the entire vector space. If this is true, then what is the point of specifying that the order of the group must not divide the characteristic of the field that the vector space is over? The only thing that I can think of is that maybe my proof does not hold for vector spaces of infinite dimensions?

Comment: You've proved applying $\rho(g)$ to $v\in W^c$ does not land you in $W$. That's not enough to show it lands back in $W^c$, though.

Answer (score 1):

**Update accounting for edits:**

I think the problem is in the first line.
Because the set-theoretic complement $W^c$ is not a subspace, it's better notationally to suppose that $V = W_1 \oplus W_2$ and that $W_1$ is $G$-invariant.
Now if you suppose (by way of contradiction) that for $v \in W_2$ you have $gv \notin W_2$, you don't get to assume that $gv \in W_1$.
All you learn is that $gv$ leaves $W_2$.

In Alexander Golys' answer, $W_1$ and $W_2$ are two lines. Applying $g$ carries $W_1$ to itself but takes $W_2$ to another line—not back into $W_1$ as your proof assumes.

Comment: My apologies, there were some major typos in my initial write up. It is supposed to be $v\in W^c$, and I show that $v\in W$ as well, and since the only element in both is the zero vector, that is how I determine $v$ must be the zero vector.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Alright, I think I got it. Between your comment and Alexander's that helps a lot, thanks! You're right, $W^c$ as the notation did mislead me there!

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly false even in cases where Mashke's theorem applies. Let $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ act on $\mathbb R^2$ by $g\cdot (x, y) = (-x, y)$. Clearly we have $V = V_1 \oplus V_2$ for $V_1 = \left<(0, 1)\right>,  V_2=\left<(1, 1)\right>$ and $V_1$ is $G$-invariant, but $V_2$ is not.

Comment: Thanks, I figured there was something wrong with the proof, can you tell me what it is?

Comment: I think you've assumed that each vector either belongs to W or its complement. But direct sum is not the set-theoretical union. For example, in case from my example, vector (1, 0) belongs to neither $V_1$ nor $V_2$.

Comment: Oh, gotcha, that helps a lot, thank you!